# How can I post multiple json objects in a single pull request comment in curl?

Tags: curl, jq, github-api, xq

I have the following output that I wanted to post to a github pull request as a comment

```
{
  "@name": "testWalletDeepLinkLoginFlow",
  "@classname": "iphone13pro-15.7-en-portrait#.AppUI-Tests.WalletDeepLinkLoginFlowTest",
  "@time": "30.246",
  "failure": "Failure at /Users/vagrant/git/AppUITests/Extensions/XCUIElement+Additions.swift:30 - Assertion Failure at XCUIElement+Additions.swift:30: Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for first query match sequence: `Descendants matching type TextField` -> `Elements matching predicate '\"input_country_search\" IN identifiers'`, given input App element pid: 627 (no attribute values faulted in)",
  "webLink": "https://console.firebase.google.com/project/app-54934/testlab/histories/bh.388190097b1eab25/matrices/9067272573409626190/details"
}
{
  "@name": "testWalletDeepLinkMainFlow",
  "@classname": "iphone13pro-15.7-en-portrait#.AppUI-Tests.WalletDeepLinkMainFlowTest",
  "@time": "50.672",
  "failure": "Failure at /Users/vagrant/git/AppUITests/DeepLinks/Wallet/WalletDeepLinkMainFlowTest.swift:17 - Assertion Failure at WalletDeepLinkMainFlowTest.swift:17: XCTAssertTrue failed",
  "webLink": "https://console.firebase.google.com/project/app-54934/testlab/histories/bh.388190097b1eab25/matrices/7233833673388432629/details"
}
```

I prepare the github pull request comment with the following method

```
generate_pull_request_payload()
{
  cat <<EOF
{
  "body": "$FAILED_TESTS"
}
EOF
}
```

I use xq command line tool to fetch only failed tests and use the output above to post to github with the following curl

```
curl -X POST "https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/issues/3943/comments" \
  -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-type: text/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "$(generate_pull_request_payload)"
```

I expected to have the output posted to a comment

Comment: What is `FAILED_TESTS`? What is the response (status code) of GitHub? (enable verbose with `curl -v`)

Comment: `FAILED_TESTS` is the result of the following `echo $(cat JUnitReport.xml) | xq -r '.testsuites.testsuite.testcase[] | select(.failure)' | jq -sR '. | @text'`

Comment: `echo $(cat JUnitReport.xml) | xq` is a very convoluted way to write `<JUnitReport.xml xq`. (Same with `cat <<EOF ... EOF` instead of `echo ...`)

Comment: you're above the complexity where bash scripting makes sense. Switch to a better scripting language, like Python, PHP, or Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to not use shell string interpolation to generate JSON; instead use `jq` directly to produce your expected output document:

```
generate_pull_request_payload()
{
  xq -r '.testsuites.testsuite.testcase[] | select(.failure)' < JUnitReport.xml \
  | jq -sR '{ body: . }'
}
```

There shouldn't be a need for `@text` if you format JSON directly, without going through plain text and string interpolation in the first place.

And eventually read the data for the post request directly from stdin:

```
generate_pull_request_payload | curl -X POST "https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/issues/3943/comments" \
  -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-type: text/json; charset=utf-8" \
  -d @-
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I was missing is to get the log output of $FAILED_TESTS as text by piping as `jq -sR '. | @text'` and I needed to remove the double quotes in the following line `"body": $FAILED_TESTS` and it worked

Comment: You could also do `jq -r` to produce raw output (without enclosing double quotes)